# Validating your APK configuration

Tags: android, google-play

when I finished upload new version on Google play, I get this message:
`"Unexpected error validating your APK configuration"`,,, please any help!

Comment: Do you have airpush ads in your app? If yes, then you'd have to remove them AFAIK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this Google Play APK publish error message mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060655/what-does-this-google-play-apk-publish-error-message-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was in portrait and landscape, when I added landscape feature it prevent update the app by some mobiles, so gave me this message