# Cannot publish updated APK: "Version 20 is not served to any device configuration"

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I'm trying to publish a new version of my application in Google Play. When I upload new APK file (app version 22) I can't see the option to publish it in production. I can save it only as a draft. There's a red message (see the screenshot below) saying:

> Version 20 is not served to any device configuration: all devices that
>   might receive version 20 would receive version 22

[image: Red warning message]

Situation doesn't get any better when I deactivate APK 20 (2.0).

What am I doing wrong? I can't figure it out.

Comment: It should work if you deactive version 20. Its weird it doesnt get better. 

that error is very usual, You can have 2 published versions of one app only if their target devices are diferente. If the are targeting the same sort of devices, you only can have one. 

Can you unpublish 20 and provide an screenshot of the new error?

Comment: What error are you getting when you deactivate version 20?

Comment: Big thanks to you guys for your help. The problem was very silly and embarrassing. I just didn't save my changes in the dashboard using the **Publish now** button. So in the end I just didn't deactivate the old version which prevented me from publishing the updated one. Shame on me :)

Comment: @bitrut these things happen (post your answer in case of someone will do the same mistake).

Comment: But how do you perform a staged rollout in this case? Do I still have to deactivate the old one? Doesn't that mean my users will not be able to download it any more?

Comment: [Here is the solution...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17935218/2959200) Hope this helps.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was very silly. I just didn't save my changes in the dashboard using the **Publish now** button. So in the end I just didn't deactivate the old version which prevented me from publishing the updated one.
Just publish your changes and you're good to go.