# Android app versionCode too large

Tags: android, google-play

I have accidentally published an APK that has a very large version code. i.e. the MAX of an integers value.

Now I cannot publish any more versions of my app because there is no larger integer for my version.

How can I resolve this problem? Is my only option to republish this as a completely new separate app?

Comment: What about reverting to an old version and then just uploading the new one with a fixed Version Code?

Comment: I have tried this. The dev console forbids you from activating an apk that had an earlier version code

Comment: Revert then upload a new one?

Comment: You should contact Google directly, they will help

Comment: how come you set it that high ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going into the Play Store Console and go to following places:

**APK Tab** --> **Switch to Advanced Mode** --> **Other APKs** --> then choose the one you want and press **"Move to Production"**.

See Image:
[image: Hi there]

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. If I push the "Move to Prod" button. This is the error "This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):
Version 2147483647 is not served to any device configuration: all devices that might receive version 64 would receive version 2147483647." Which kinda makes the feature useless imo.

Comment: Hmm, I would suggest contacting Google before you remove it.

Comment: Forgot to like, my apologies.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17935218/1064310 if waiting does not help I would suggest contacting Google