# Unable to update apk in Google PlayStore

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I am facing some problem updating my apk in Google playstore. It was working fine when I updated my app on last Jan 7. However when I tried to update my app yesterday it giving me following error

> This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):
>   Version 47 is not served to any device configuration: all devices that might receive version 47 would receive version 50.

I checked the issue and they are saying change your VersionCode to integer but in my case it is already an Integer and I am not declaring VersionCode anywhere else except build.gradle file.

Google added a new flag for ads in pricing and distribution so today I added that field but still having same problem.

**Note:** There is no problem with my keystore file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this Google Play APK publish error message mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060655/what-does-this-google-play-apk-publish-error-message-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened when you published two APKs (versions x and then y) in a short space of time. Clicking "Deactivate" on the dropdown next to version x appeared to fix it.

more detail refer [What does this Google Play APK publish error message mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060655/what-does-this-google-play-apk-publish-error-message-mean)

Comment: But I already deactivated my draft build before pushing new apk.

Comment: is there any apk in draft  ?

Comment: that same apk you want to published ?

Comment: yes, and just now I deactivated older one. Shhould i wait till it get unpublished from all Google Play Servers?

Comment: Awesome, it worked. Thanks, that really gave me a headache :p