# Error message showing while uploading Apk to the google play store

Tags: android, google-play, apk

[image: Screenshot]

I have apk on play store with with version code 5 and version name 5.0.0. But when I am trying to upload new apk to play store with version code 6 and version name 5.0.1 it showing me this error as

**This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):**

**Version 5 is not served to any device configuration: all devices that might receive version 5 would receive version 6.**

**Some devices are eligible to run multiple APKs. In such a scenario, the device will receive the APK with the higher version code.**

I have even check out the dependency, permissions and menifest files there is no changes with old version. 
I have seen  though this like on the stack as well
[What does this Google Play APK publish error message mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060655/what-does-this-google-play-apk-publish-error-message-mean) but in may case all version code as on the store(i.e. 1-5).

Comment: What's your API level?

Answer (score 0):

Just unpublish the older one (version code 5 and version name 5.0.0) as the new version makes the older one redundant.