# Unable to resolve: Google Play: This configuration cannot be published for the following reasons"

Tags: cordova, google-play

Can someone with Google Play Developer experience tell me what to try next?

In the Google Play Developer Portal I can't seem to get any apk to get published. A March 2016 apk has a button for "deactivate." I uploaded one with a later Cordova version, but set the apk version lower than that by mistake. That's the apk listed on the bottom. I rectified the mistake and updated the version in config.xml. That's the apk listed above Deactivate. Clicking on Move to the right of the newer uploads reveals the Delete option, which doesn't do anything at all. I uploaded another apk with a higher version number -- that's the top apk.

Clicking on Deactivate for the original upload does not make the message go away, and there is no Publish button appearing anywhere either. Clicking on Deactivate moves the apk to "Other APKs" and the button for all the remaining APKs have options of Move to Alpha, Move to Beta, and Delete. Clicking on Move to Alpha for all but one moved them to "Other APKs," and I still did not get a Publish button for the remaining one. Delete was not working for those APKs that were moved to "Other APKs."

I did a cordova platform rm android / cordova platform add android and uploaded the latest apk to Google Play. After I clicked on the Saved draft button, I got: "The application could not be saved. Please check the form for errors." Scrolling carefully to the full top and bottom did not reveal any errors for that APK. Canceling the action was my only option.

In red, it says:

> This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):
>
> Version 1301008 is not served to any device configuration: all devices
>   that might receive version 1301008 would receive version 1302000.
>
> Version 1300118 is not served to any device configuration: all devices
>   that might receive version 1300118 would receive version 1302000.
>
> Version 1300038 is not served to any device configuration: all devices
>   that might receive version 1300038 would receive version 1302000.
>
> Version 1300108 is not served to any device configuration: all devices
>   that might receive version 1300108 would receive version 1302000.
>
> Some
>   devices are eligible to run multiple APKs. In such a scenario, the
>   device will receive the APK with the higher version code.

At this point, it appears that I need to rename the APK and release it as a new APK, meaning, of course, that my subs can't get it as an update. **What are my options now?**

Issue is very similar to:

> [What does this Google Play APK publish error message mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060655/what-does-this-google-play-apk-publish-error-message-mean)

I tried the solutions offered there, but the buttons at right did not behave as this page expected.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to rename APK. The problem might be that one is in the draft and the other is ready to publish.

If there are two APKs then you need to deactivate current apk and publish the new one.

If this doesn't help, please write to google from your developer console and they will reply with solution

Comment: Deactivating does not have any effect, unfortunately. Thank you -- I did not see the section to ask Google for help. I have sent them an email.

Comment: If you click on help on top right , email support is listed at bottom of dropdown. Once resolved, please share your findings.

Comment: I will report what they suggest.