# Android dev console: Cannot publish application

Tags: android, apk, developer-console

Just upgraded an app from V12 to V13 - text change in help only. Works fine.

Go up upload it to dev. console and it will not publish the new APK, says:

"This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):
Version 12 is not served to any device configuration: all devices that might receive version 12 would receive version 13."

What is it talking about? V12 was published for 40K+ devices, I've just done exactly the same thing to three other apps with no problem, but this one won't have it.

No idea what it means. All I can do is save it as draft.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this Google Play APK publish error message mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060655/what-does-this-google-play-apk-publish-error-message-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is known problem of Google developer console.

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060655/what-does-this-google-play-apk-publish-error-message-mean)

Answer (score 0):

When you upload a new version of an app, you need to **manually** deactivate the previous version, until you do, the dev console won't let you publish the new state.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers above equally good. I had tried the second one and it didn't work. Went back a few hours later, still didn't work, did the second answer again, and it did. Very strange ....