# APK "Publish Now" in timed publishing mode

Tags: android, google-play, apk, publish

In google play store,I have enabled timed publishing.

when I uploaded new APK in production , I see "Publish Now" button.

What does "Publish Now" will do in case of timed publishing , will it only submit for review and wait for me to press "Go Live" ?

(or) Will it make the binary available to public,once the review is complete ?

Answer (score 0):

It will publish it for review, and when review is finished you can publish it from the Go Live button.

PS: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060655/what-does-this-google-play-apk-publish-error-message-mean) If you publish new build before the old ones are distributed you need to manually deactivate the older ones.

Comment: When I tried to "Publish now" , its giving error i think because the old binary is still Active/In Prod status , Do i need to Deactivate old binary before clicking "Publish now" on new binary ?

Comment: @RavikanthM You dont need to deactivate your old binary(its happening automatically when you go live). Is there an error message? or any red text appearing?

Comment: This is the error message i am getting in red text ==>                                                     This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):
·         Version 85 is not served to any device configuration: all devices that might receive version 85 would receive version 86.
·         Version 44 is not served to any device configuration: all devices that might receive version 44 would receive version 86.

Comment: Ok it seems you have to deactivate your old builds- according to this you published several build in a row: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060655/what-does-this-google-play-apk-publish-error-message-mean

Comment: Does deactivating old build makes my app not available in playstore until my new build is processed and published ?

Comment: @RavikanthM it might, but even if it does- all users that have the app can continue using it. And the downtime would be less than an hour until the new build is up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136884/discussion-between-x3btel-and-ravikanthm).

Answer (score 0):

Ref: **https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282**

Publish with timed publishing 
Step 1: turn on timed publishing
1. Go to your Google Play Developer Console.
2. Select an app.
3. Near the top of the screen, select the publishing mode drop-down Drop-down arrow. By default, you'll see "Standard publishing".
4. Select Turn on timed publishing.
5. Review details about timed publishing, then click Turn on.
6. After you’ve made your update, click Submit update. Your update will be processed as usual. This can take up to a few hours.
7.To review your update, click View change log.

**Step 2: publish your app update

1. Once your update has been processed and you're ready to publish, select Go live.

2. Review the change log and select Go live. Your update will be live on Google Play within a few minutes.**

Comment: Do i need to Deactivate old binary before before "Submit update" ?, its giving error when "Submit update" , i think because the old binary is still Active/In Prod status.

Comment: Yes deactivate the older, Since your app is review completed and ready to publish.

Comment: Does deactivating old build makes my app not available in playstore until my new build is processed and published ?

Comment: No way.. go publish.. try re-install your app, you could able to download the older version until new version is published