# Trying to publish to GooglePlay appStore gives error 403

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play, visual-studio-mac

Trying to upload the version 39 of the app, the error message I get is:

> Error uploading 'foo.bar.baz'
>
> Version 38 of this app cannot be downloaded by any devices as they will all receive APKs with higher version codes. [403]

Screenshot:
[image: VSMac screenshot of the error]

What does this exactly mean? I'm trying to publish as "Alpha" from VisualStudio for Mac (the current version 38 of the alpha channel was uploaded manually.)

Comment: Did you increase the version number?

Comment: yes I did, it's 36 while the latest in the GooglePlay console is 35

Comment: I suspect you still have APK version code 1 as a "retained APK" in your release. Can you show a screenshot of your "manage releases" page. I suspect you still have an on version code 1 around.

Comment: now everything on the Alpha lane, still similar error message (see edits and screenshot)

Comment: Can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060655/what-does-this-google-play-apk-publish-error-message-mean

Comment: From the screenshot it appears you're trying to publish apk with version 39 and error is for apk with version 38. Please see that you have deactivated apk with version 38 like others have mentioned.

Comment: @knocte did you manage to solve this?

Comment: nope, see my reply to Krzysztof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in Visual Studio for Mac, so [I reported it here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/303686/trying-to-upload-an-android-release-to-googleplay.html). Hopefully they fix it soon.

Answer (score 0):

The `Version number` (integer-based) is set via the `versionCode` in the manifest must be increased each time you submit to the Play Store no matter if it is submitted as an Alpha, Beta, or Release APK.

Either via the Project Options / Build / Android Application :

[image]

Or via manually editing the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:versionCode="18"
```

Comment: yeah I already increased that, it's bigger than the latest release

Comment: @knocte ? The error says `Version 1` . Version Number and Name are different, Name is just that a name, it can be anything and is what is shown to the user, the Number (`versionCode`) has to be incremented upon every submission, wether or not that apk is ever released

Comment: it's weird, I don't know where does that number `1` come from then

Comment: @knocte That number comes from `versionCode` in the manifest and thus `Version name` in the project options.

Comment: nope, in Version number I have the value `36` and in Version name I have the value `0.4.0.36`

Comment: @knocte Try double checking the final manifest in the apk just to sure.

Comment: it's correct, I double checked, because uploading the APK manually works

Comment: I updated the answer to now not involve the InternalTest lane at all, just the alpha, see screenshot.

Answer (score -1):

If I remember correctly I've had a similar issue when I was trying to update an apk with higher version code to beta, when there was still apk with lower version code in alpha.

Since you are trying to upgrade on alpha, maybe you have an apk on internal test track with version code 38? If that is the case, I would deactivate version uploaded to internal test tract (or update it to version code 39) and then update version on alpha

Comment: how to deactivate it? I don't find the option to do it

Comment: there's no UI in the GooglePlay Console website to deactivate releases, only way to do it now seems to be when rolling out a new release manually